# SetForceCacheRefresh?

Tags: nhibernate

How do I re-read some (class) Items from the database? I have read them once and made same updates, updates I dont wont to save. Now I need a complete fresh collection of Items from the database.

I have noticed that there are a function called SetForceCacheRefresh, but how do I use it with a CreateCriteria?

// Mats

Answer (score 1):

```
             IList<T> list = null;
             using (Repository rep = new Repository())
             {
                IQuery iqry = rep.Session.CreateQuery(hql);                    
                iqry.SetForceCacheRefresh(true);
                list = iqry.List<T>();
             }
```

Note: Before calling List(), set SetForceCacheRefresh(true) to refresh.